# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:6.2.1?

Tags: mapbox

i adding gradle for my project, but i have error like this ?
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:6.2.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the link below would help, move the `maven {url: url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }` to `allProjects` as outlined in the link here. [enter link description here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/1381#issuecomment-428654714)